# Add 3rd party library to Google Cloud Virtual Machine

Tags: python, docker, virtual-machine, google-cloud-platform, boot2docker

I want to setup a Virtual Machine on Google Cloud Platform and use a third party library. I've followed the instruction [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/) to set everything up in python, but I'm not sure how to proceed. I would like to add [this library](https://github.com/mailgun/talon). What would be the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some troubleshooting this was the solution that worked:

Dockerfile

```
FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/python-compat

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl gcc python-dev g++ libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
ADD requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD . /app
```

requirements.txt

```
talon==1.0.2
```